# npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none was installed

Tags: angular, npm

> npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of
>   @angular/core@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
>       npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
>       npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/http@^2.3.0 but none was installed.
>       npm WARN bootstrap@4.1.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.3 but none was installed.

I am trying to install **angular2-text-mask** for US phone number input format.
Any help please?

Comment: You're missing appropriate versions of angular/core, common, and http. Install them via `npm install @angular/core@2.3.0`

Comment: version of angular is 1.6.6

Comment: Then you can't use angular2-text-mask, as it's for angular2 as the name suggests. Check out their documentation and you'll find that there's [angular1-text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular1#readme)